# Are there any general drawbacks from using java.lang.ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local, thread-local-storage

Each time you use `String.format()`, a new instance of `java.util.Formatter` is created that will be disposed afterwards.

Just because I was curious, I played around with that a bit to make the use of `format()` a little more efficient, by caching the `Formatter` object. Unfortunately, `Formatter` is not thread-safe, and any means of synchronisation would eat up any performance gain you can get from caching it.

Finally, I found the solution below:

```
import java.util.Formatter;

    /*------------------------*\
====** Static Initialisations **===========================================
    \*------------------------*/
/**
 *  The initial buffer size that is used by
 *  {@link #format(String, Object...)}
 *  and
 *  {@link #format(Locale, String, Object...)}
 *  (per thread): {@value}.
 */
public final static int FORMAT_INITIAL_BUFFERSIZE = 2048;

/**
 *  The cached
 *  {@link Formatter}
 *  instance.
 */
private static final ThreadLocal<Formatter> m_Formatter;

static
{
    //---* The cached Formatter instance *---------------------------------
    final Supplier<Formatter> initializer = () -> new Formatter( new StringBuilder( FORMAT_INITIAL_BUFFERSIZE ), Locale.getDefault( Locale.Category.FORMAT ) );
    m_Formatter = ThreadLocal.<Formatter>withInitial( initializer );
}

    /*---------*\
====** Methods **==========================================================
    \*---------*/
/**
 *  Returns a formatted String using the specified
 *  {@link Locale},
 *  format String, and arguments.<br>
 *  <br>This method is meant as a replacement for the method
 *  {@link java.lang.String#format(String, Object...)};
 *  that implementation always uses a new instance of
 *  {@link Formatter}
 *  for each invocation. The implementation here uses a cached instance
 *  instead, and as {@code Formatter} is not inherently thread-safe, this
 *  cached instance is created and stored per thread, therefore no
 *  synchronisation is needed.<br>
 *  <br>The performance gain for this implementation is not that impressive
 *  when compared with that of
 *  {@link #format(String, Object...)},
 *  but still in the 10% range.
 *  {@code java.lang.String.format()}.
 *
 *  @param  locale  The
 *      {@link Locale}
 *      that will be applied during formatting. If {@code locale} is
 *      {@code null} then no localisation is applied.
 *  @param  format  A format String with the syntax as described for the
 *      {@link Formatter}
 *      class.
 *  @param  args    The arguments referenced by the format specifiers in
 *      the {@code format} String. If there are more arguments than format
 *      specifiers, the extra arguments are ignored. The number of
 *      arguments is variable and may be zero. The maximum number of
 *      arguments is limited by the maximum dimension of a Java array as
 *      defined by <cite>The Java&trade; Virtual Machine
 *      Specification</cite>. The behaviour on a {@code null} argument
 *      depends on the conversion.
 *  @throws IllegalFormatException A format string contains an illegal
 *      syntax, a format specifier that is incompatible with the given
 *      arguments, insufficient arguments given the format string, or other
 *      illegal conditions occurred. For specification of all possible
 *      formatting errors, see the &quot;Details&quot; section of the
 *      {@code Formatter} class specification.
 *  @return A formatted String.
 *
 *  @see  java.util.Formatter
 */
@SuppressWarnings( "resource" )
public final static String format( final Locale locale, final String format, final Object... args ) throws IllegalFormatException
{
    /*
     * When this method StringUtils.format() is used inside an
     * implementation of Formattable.formatTo() that in turn was called by
     * this method already, the internal out buffer of the formatter
     * contains already some text that has to be preserved.
     *
     * Therefore the current length of the out buffer is kept before new
     * contents is added by the call to formatter.format(), and reset after
     * the new formatted text was retrieved from that buffer.
     */
    final var formatter = m_Formatter.get();
    final var result = (StringBuilder) formatter.out();
    final var currentPos = result.length();
    formatter.format( locale, format, args );
    final var retValue = result.substring( currentPos );
    result.setLength( currentPos );

    //---* Done *----------------------------------------------------------
    return retValue;
}   //  format()
```

The cached `Formatter` instance is hold in an instance of `java.lang.ThreadLocal`, so each Thread has its own instance and no synchronisation is required.

So far it is working; extensive tests did not show any problems so far, and some (artificial) benchmarks show a performance gain of about 10% compared to the use of `java.lang.String.format()`; that gain is constant on any (class of) machine I ran the tests on.

An obvious disadvantage of this solution is that the memory footprint for each thread that uses my `format()` implementation is increased by around half a kB plus the size of the initial buffer (see the source).

But I can faintly remember some statements that using `java.lang.ThreadLocal` is *evil*, although I cannot remember any reason why … basically, you can boil it down to "there are rumours …".

Or not? Is there something that I missed about the use of `java.util.ThreadLocal` in the way I did?

Please do not discuss whether replacing `String.format()` with my solution might be useful or not: I just did it – as said – because I was curious whether it could made faster by caching the `Formatter` instance – nothing else.

Edit (based on some of the comments that have been added to the question):

- That the `Formatter` instance will never be removed from the Thread is intended. But there is no need to keep the size of the associated `StringBuilder` at its current size when it was extended above the initial size.
- There is an issue with `ThreadLocal` in the context of 'managed environments' (Application Servers and Web Servers) because there Threads are re-used, and therefore, the data stored in the `ThreadLocal` will never be garbage collected, as the `ThreadLocal` will never be released.

Comment: The most evil part in this particular case is you never clean up the threadlocal, so the object lingers until the thread dies. On pool threads that's a long time.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: Yeah, but that is intended. I keep it because I want to reuse it. Of course, if the thread made only one single call to format() in its whole lifetime, that's a waste of memory – but when you know that before, you can still use String.format() …

Comment: maybe this is the article you were looking for: https://plumbr.io/blog/locked-threads/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-foot-with-threadlocals - basically, it's a memory leak, and although intentional, sometimes it still means there's stuff in threadlocal storage that can no longer be cleaned up by anyone because the app that knew it was there no longer loaded.

Comment: A usually overlooked consequence of using thread locals is in JEE or even servlet container environments (e.g. tomcat). In this case, your app's classes are container managed, and so are the threads (you do not create them, the container does). When you use a ThreadLocal, you link the container thread to your app's class and thus classloader. As the thread will probably never die, neither will your class loader, and no static variable will ever be released / GC'ed unless you shutdown the container completely. It may end up with a "I have a memory leak" post on SO in 6 months :-)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: the Application Classloader is tied only to objects that are loaded by it. All classes I use will be loaded by the System Classloader that is the Parent Classloader (although I have no clue what loads the lambda that I use to initialise). And all OOM scenarios described assume that the container threads will live longer than the application … but common practice has got to recycle the whole container instead of a single application. In times of Docker, the whole "machine" is recycled. Nevertheless, the documents you referred me to was what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: I doubt that you are able to calculate the impact of a single temporary formatter instance on the garbage collection. An artificial benchmark doing in a loop what you’re normally don’t execute that often does not help. The 10% difference are likely caused by the `StringBuilder`’s initial capacity of 16 characters, which requires it to increase the capacity multiple times, copying the entire contents, which doesn’t happen when reusing a builder. But creating a temporary `Formatter` with a `StringBuilder` specifying a more reasonable initial capacity may have the same effect.

Comment: @Holger: As I had the same idea about the `StringBuilder`, I ran the benchmarks without an increased initial size for the `StringBuilder`, assuming that creates equal terms for both implementations. But as said, the usefulness of the implementation was not the intention for this question.

Comment: It seems, you didn’t get the point. I didn’t even notice that you also provide an increased initial size; it doesn’t matter anyway. When you *reuse* a `StringBuilder`, it does already have a higher capacity, regardless of its initial capacity. Sharing does eliminate the issue of the initial capacity, whether you specify a higher capacity or not. To have a useful comparison, you need a scenario where you don’t reuse the builder, but specify a higher capacity. And when you ask, “Are there any general drawbacks…”, not actually solving any problem and reducing the performance would be an answer.

Comment: Have you actually _measured_ a performance improvement from re-using `Formatter` instances? The idea that a program will create large numbers of objects with very short lifetimes is baked in to Java, and most Java garbage collectors are designed to deal with that case very efficiently.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Re-using a `Formatter` instance had been my starting point, and as that showed already a difference in performance, I dug deeper. But when adding synchronisation, all performance gain got lost again, and I looked for alternatives … ending up with a solution using `ThreadLocal` that made synchronisation obsolete. But again, the question is arbout the use of `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: @Holger: So your comment is that the use of `ThreadLocal` will not (never?) solve any problems, and that it will reduce performance. Can you please elaborate on that? I am particularly interested in the perfomance loss: is it in general or compared with what other solutions?

Comment: Using `ThreadLocal` is not the problem. It’s just the fundamental “reusing vs temporary object” issue. For most environments, reusing objects only pays off when the construction of the object has a significant weight. A `Formatter` is a lightweight wrapper around a `StringBuilder`, which is a lightweight wrapper around a `char[]` array. Their allocation bears no costs at all. As said, the only thing that could bear costs are capacity expansions, as they imply copying of the already contained characters. Things look different for objects or resources, whose construction truly was expensive…

Comment: FWIW, and IMO, The main use-case for `ThreadLocal` is when you are required to port old, single-threaded code that depends on `static` variables to a multi-threaded environment. Replacing `static GlobalState global_state` with `static ThreadLocal<GlobalState> global_state`, is an easy way to let each thread use the library independently of any other thread.\* Personally, I try pretty hard to avoid `static` in new code, and consequently, I never have had any use for `ThreadLocal` in new code.

Comment: \* But NOTE! This trick will go down in flames if somebody writes code that calls in to your newly 'thread-safe' library from within tasks that are submitted to a thread pool!!! Use it with caution!!

Comment: @SolomonSlow: I got your point, but the issue is with all state on globally accessible objects, not only with `static` variables. And the issue with pooled threads is when you make assumptions about the initial state (forget the memory considerations that were mentioned already elsewhere). Nevertheless, you are right: that could cause funny effects!